# Hilt cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have a viewmodel for activity

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: UserRepository
)     : ViewModel() {

}
```

Repository interface

```
interface UserRepository {
suspend fun loginUser(username: String, password: String): Pair<Boolean, String>
}
```

User data source class is as follows

```
internal class UserDataSource @Inject constructor(private val octaveApi: OctaveApi) :
UserRepository {

override suspend fun loginUser(username: String, password: String): Pair<Boolean, String> {
    return Pair(false, "unsucess")
}
}
```

This is my dagger implementation

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class ApiModule {

  @Module
  @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
  object Providers {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideOctaveApi(retrofit: Retrofit): OctaveApi =
      retrofit.create(OctaveApi::class.java)
  }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)
abstract class RetainedDataModule {

  @Binds
  internal abstract fun bindUserRepository(userDataSource: UserDataSource):     UserRepository
}
```

When I build the project I get this error

```
/OctaveDashboard/app/build/generated/source/kapt/stagingExternalDebug/com/octave/OctaveApplication_HiltComponents.java:125: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.octave.data.user.UserRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements OctaveApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                     ^
  com.octave.data.user.UserRepository is injected at
      com.octave.MainViewModel(cornersRepository)
  com.octave.MainViewModel is injected at
      com.octave.MainViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
  @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
      dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.octave.OctaveApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.octave.OctaveApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.octave.OctaveApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

Can't seem to figure out what's causing the issue.

Comment: I'll assume `UserDataSource` has `@Inject` added to its constructor?

Comment: @MarkKeen yes it injects the octaveApi object. I have added the class

Comment: All these classes are in the same module? I noticed you have internal visibility modifier for some reason.

Comment: @MarkKeen have multiple modules. UserDataSource and api module is in 1 module. Userrepository is in 2nd module and mainviewmodel is in app module

Comment: Probably want internal in your constructor only.

Comment: Are you running the Hilt annotation processor on both modules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was missing module dependencies in my app module which was creating this issue. Was able to fix by including it.

Comment: This was my problem too. Thank you :)

Comment: I just started with Composer and I'm having this problem. Could you give us more details on the module to add?

Comment: It's not a good thing to read an article for a time, then, there's not a complete answer available like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Provides to your function

```
 internal class UserDataSource @Inject constructor(private val octaveApi: OctaveApi) :
UserRepository {

@Provides
override suspend fun loginUser(username: String, password: String): Pair<Boolean, String> {
    return Pair(false, "unsucess")
}
}
```